# Uploading to Discord with discord.py from Dropbox

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, dropbox, dropbox-api

I made a Dropbox bot that can access all folders on the account and added the token to my discord bot's code. Access to `files.content.read` and `files.metadata.read` are enabled.

Some files such as mp3 files don't have previews when you only post a URL so I want to actually upload the files in a Dropbox folder using the bot.

I read the [File Properties](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/file_properties.html) and [Files](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html) section of the Dropbox API documentation but I couldn't find out how to return a file-like object. For now, I wanna do image and audio files.

I tried this:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("Test was called.")
    
    file_name = "stonks.jpg"
    my_file = dropbox.files('/Reaction Pics/' + file_name)
    await ctx.channel.send(file=my_file)
```

But I get the following error: (I have checked that my drop box API has access to that file.)

```
    my_file = dropbox.files('/Reaction Pics/' + file_name)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you try working through the [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial) linked on that documentation page?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah. It only mentioned how to print filenames in a directory, printing metadata of a file, and uploading a file.

Answer (score 0):

`dropbox.files` is a module, not a method for interacting with files on Dropbox.

Instead, to get the file content from Dropbox (so you can then upload it elsewhere), you should use [the `files_download` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download). There's [an example of using that here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/7b111c5f75aecb5ccb9efba1d0f9747ebc131908/example/updown.py#L159).

(Alternatively, you can use [`files_download_to_file`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download_to_file) to save it to disk first. [Example here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/7b111c5f75aecb5ccb9efba1d0f9747ebc131908/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py#L55).)

Comment: I did see the download method but I don't want to save it to disk. I was hoping there was a way to upload it to discord without saving it to disk cause I'm using a free cloud hosting for the bot.

Comment: To be clear, only the `files_download_to_file` method automatically saves the download to disk. The `files_download` method does not save to disk. It gives the file data in memory. (It's in `res.content` in the linked example, for instance.)